# Automatically increment input type="hidden" value

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, button

I have this line of code

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#update").click(function(){
$("#id2").css("display","hidden");
var r = $("#id2").val()+1;
$("#id2").val(r);
});
});
</script>
        <title>CV Education Form</title>
       .
       .
       .
       .
        </fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id2" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 1 : $id );?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit"/>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and I want to change it to hidden so it is invisble but also when i click on a button update (which I have it) then it increments the value (**$id**) ... More simple i want something like that id+1.

Do you know how can I do that?

[image]

When I click on update button i want the 1 which is the $id to become $id+1 but I dont want to add myself I want to do it automatically when i click the update button and also hide the textfield

Comment: use js for this job.

Comment: yes but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Have you tried anything or even searched for this I am sure you can find this easily.

Comment: Maybe i am searching on the wrong way . For example i am searching this "how can I auto increment the value of an input type="hidden"". Maybe it is wrong , can you suggest me another way to search it

Comment: yupp u are searing in the wrong way search for changing input type separately and incrementing separately and u will definetly get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the update button id and id of the inputs. Use the code below

```
     <html>
        <head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
        <body>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#update").click(function(){
$("#id2").css("display","none");
var r = parseInt($("#id2").val(),10)+1;
$("#id2").val(r);
});
});

</script>
        <title>CV Education Form</title>
       .
       .
       .
       .
        </fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id2" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 1 : $id );?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="update" name="submit"/>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Check it here 
http://jsfiddle.net/53cov3uq/3/

Hope this helps you

Comment: the script tag should i place them in the php tags and also the type I want to be hidden and be incremented when i click on update button

Comment: The code above is doing all the task that you mentioned.

Comment: where should i place the script tags in the php tags or in the html tags ?

Comment: Place them in html tags

Comment: Hey listen replace #update in $("#update") with your update button od

Comment: Ya in this code just specify its id and in jquery specify its id

Comment: I edit my code please take a loop and tell me exactly if you want what should i do

Comment: Updated my answer have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function increment_val(){
   var id_val = parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value);
   id_val++;
   document.getElementById('id').value=id_val;
}
</script>
```

and in button html call js function,

```
<input type="button" value="update" id="btn_id" onclick="increment_val();"/>
```

Comment: I edited my question can you please be more specific where should i place it

Comment: i assumed you didn't used jQuery. Place the Code inside <script> tag in head or after body. Use this button for update

Answer (score 1):

you can do it very simply using either Jquery or JavaScript .find the code below

```js
function update()
{
  var count=parseInt($('#counter').val());
  $('#counter').val(count+1);
  alert($('#counter').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="counter" name="id" value="0"/>
<button onclick="update()">update</button>
```

i just kept alert at the end that will popup the current value of the id.

Answer (score 0):

For that use javascript. Php is server-side script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function increment()
  {
    var elem = document.getElementById("hiddenElement");
    elem.value = 1 + parseInt(elem.value);
  }
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenElement" name="id" value="0" />
<button onclick="increment()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which increments the value on click of a button.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id').value = document.getElementById('id').value + 1;">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 1 : $id );?>" />
```

To change input type you can use the syntax like:

```
$("#id").attr('type','hidden');
```

To increment the value use

```
document.getElementById('id').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value)+1;
```

or using jquery

```
$("#id").val($("#id").val()+1);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to change text to hidden element and increment value

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 1 : $id );?>" />
<button onclick="increment_value()">Update</button>
```

JS:

```
function increment_value()
{
    var txt_field = document.getElementsByName("id")[0];
    txt_field.value = parseInt(txt_field.value) + 1;
    txt_field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
}
```

OR

If you want to simply hide the text field just use this version of the above function

```
function increment_value()
{
    var txt_field = document.getElementsByName("id")[0];
    txt_field.value = parseInt(txt_field.value) + 1;
    txt_field.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 1 : $id );?>" />
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#id").val($("#id").val()+1);
  })
})
```

Comment: OP wants to change input type to hidden on an event.

Comment: I will update my question with a print screen check in a min.